# Установка Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Не могу установить Visual Studio, пишет:
Невозможно найти продукт, соответствующий следующим параметрам:

channelId: VisualStudio.15.Release
productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте решение из форума visualstudio https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/139177/channelid-visualstudio15release-1541.html

It help for me: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe" -full

VERY IMPORTANT: You must run it several times - If You have run install and get Error message several times.

Then delete this folder:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio

For me it works.